# Binding a DataGrid TwoWay to an ObservableList of objects

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-4.0, 2-way-object-databinding

I have a class to store data:

```
public enum ColumnType
{
...
}

public class LogColumn
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ColumnType Type { get; set; }
    public bool OrderBy { get; set; }
}
```

and a ObservableCollection of it in my UserControl:

```
private ObservableCollection<LogColumn> _logColumns = new ObservableCollection<LogColumn>();
public ObservableCollection<LogColumn> LogColumns
{
    get { return _logColumns; }
    set
    {
        _logColumns = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("LogColumns");
     }
 }
```

This collection is bound to a DataGrid:

```
<DataGrid Name="dgColumnSelection"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding LogColumns, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus, Mode=TwoWay, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}" CanUserAddRows="False" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" IsReadOnly="True" Binding="{Binding Name, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus, Mode=TwoWay,  ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}" />
        <DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Type" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource ColumnType}}" SelectedValueBinding="{Binding Type, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus, Mode=TwoWay,  ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}" />
        <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="Order by" Binding="{Binding OrderBy, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus, Mode=TwoWay, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

But neither PropertyChanged-event nor Validation is fired. Where is my fault?

Thx.
Best regards

Comment: You'll have to implement INotifyPropertyChanged in your custom class for this to work.

Comment: it's already implemented it in observable collection so no need to implemented it.

Answer (score 1):

The event is never fired because you are never setting the LogColumns variable to something new.  What you are doing is changing properties on the LogColumn items contained within the LogColumns collection.

Implementing the INotifyPropertyChanged interface on your LogColumn class will might help do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

ObservableCollection only notify if the items of ObservableCollection get chagned not the items item get changed to do so you need to implement the inotifyproprty chagned in your logcolumns class

as

```
 public class LogColumn : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private string _Name;

        public string Name
        {
            get { return _Name; }
            set { _Name = value; Onchanged("Name"); }
        }
        private ColumnType _Type;


        public ColumnType Type
        {
            get { return _Type; }
            set { _Type = value; Onchanged("Type"); }
        }
        private bool _OrderBy;

        public bool OrderBy
        {
            get { return _OrderBy; }
            set { _OrderBy = value; Onchanged("OrderBy"); }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        public void Onchanged(string name)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));

        }
    }
```

now this will work.

Comment: I changed the class to derive INotifyPropertyChanged but I still get changed messages for adding new items not for changeing their properties.